# Oracle requests proxy

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, proxy

I would like to monitor all the requests made to remote server. I was thinking to create a local proxy server, make all the requests to my local server and then server connects to remote server.

There a millions of other ways to solve this, but currently there is no better solution for an big and old asp site and slow and old development tools (interdev).

So, is this a database specific problem or can it be solved with simple server forwarding? I noticed MySQL offers simple solutions for this, but I did not find anything useful for oracle.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Its not clear what "type" of requests you want to monitor,  HTTP requests into you Web server or SQL query requests into your database server?

Comment: Of course I want to monitor all the sql requests so that I can see what is being sent to server..

I do apologize ...

Answer (score 0):

You have different choices, of course, this can slowdown the server.

If you can modify the code after a new connection, just execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;
```

For more detailed info use the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET EVENT=’10046 trace name context forever, level 12’;
```

If you want for "ALL" the database, just add the following parameter on the init/spinit:

```
Event=’10046 trace name context forever, level 12’;
```

References:

- [Create Oracle Trace file for 10046](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_10046_enable_trace.htm)
- [Levels on event 10046](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/level+on+event%23+10046)

Answer (score 0):

[AUDIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#sthref1684) may do what you need, but I think it will need to be set on the remote database (and is best if there is a dedicated user account for the database link)